# three.js premultipliedAlpha=true does not affect the output of gl.readPixels()

Tags: three.js, webgl

Okay, I'm probably missing something obvious here. What I'm trying to accomplish is storing a three.js scene that has `premultipliedAlpha: true` to a buffer. However, when reading the Webgl context using `gl.readPixels()` the value of the pixels color are always as if premultipliedAlpha was set to false. Or put differently, the premultipliedAlpha flag does not affect the output of gl.readPixels().

Code example:

```js
var width = 512;
var height = 512;

// Browser renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true, premultipliedAlpha: true});
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Setup basic scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-width/2, width/2, height/2, -height/2, 0.001, 1000);
camera.position.z = 1;

// Draw a semi-transparent red square
var redSquare = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent : true,
        color: 0xFF0000,
        opacity : .5
    })
);
scene.add(redSquare);
renderer.render( scene, camera );

// Check color of first pixel
var gl = renderer.getContext();
var buf = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
console.log(buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"></script>
```

The output color is `127 0 0 127`, I expected it to be `255 0 0 127`. Toggling premultipliedAlpha changes the value on screen, but not in the output. This might be by design, but then my question is, how do I convert the color in the buffer so that I do get the expected value?

**Solution**

To premultiply the alpha in the buffer, the pixel values should be divided by the alpha value, like so:

```
buf[0] /= buf[3] / 0xff
buf[1] /= buf[3] / 0xff
buf[2] /= buf[3] / 0xff
```

Thanks to @Kirill Dmitrenko

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Calling readPixels is pretty much never the right solution. You say you expect the output to be 255, 0, 0, 127 but that would never be a correct value for `premultiplyAlpha: true`. Meaning while you could fix your code to output that value, without calling readPixels, if you are leaving `premultplyAlpha: true` then that's an invalid value. 255, 0, 0, 127 translated to 0 to 1 ranges is `r =1`, `g = 0`, `b = 0`, `a = 0.5`.  premultipliedAlpha means `r` is multiplied by `a`. That means `r` can't be more than `a` for any valid values.

Comment: Invalid values are outside the spec. How they get displayed is up to the browser. Firefox used to display them differently than Chrome for example They're currently the same but there's no guarantee they'll stay that way.

Answer (score 3):

`premultipliedAlpha: true` is the default but setting that to true or false has nothing to do with the what values are in the canvas (ie, returned from `readPixels`). It's only a flag to the browser on how to composite the canvas with the rest of the page.

It's your responsibility to put values in the canvas that match whatever you set `premultipliedAlpha` to be

Comment: It also effects things like `toDataURL`: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.4

Comment: Hi @gman, I think it also behave differently in Firefox and other browsers: here is more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216022/webgl-gl-fragcolor-alpha-behave-differently-in-chrome-with-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `premultipliedAlpha: true` is [default value](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L55).

Comment: The output of the pixel value is unaffected by the premultipliedAlpha flag - true or false. The color on screen changes, the color in the gl context buffer does not.

Comment: `premultipliedAlpha` tells browser how you store colours in the default framebuffer: multiplied by alpha or not. It's needed for compositor to correctly blend your webgl content with the rest of the page. The flags doesn't affect values written to the framebuffer. If you set it to true or false it's your responsibility to return correct colour values from fragment shaders.

Comment: Alright, suppose that I like the colors with premultipliedAlpha set to true better then without. Is there some formula for me to convert the colors in the buffer so those are the same? Currently right-click saving the canvas leads to a nicer image then when saving the pixel-buffer to a file.

Comment: Just multiply all colour (r, g and b) components by alpha.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logical. Could you spell out the formula? How to make `127 0 0 127` into `255 0 0 127`? And of course I have more then one color in the scene, so I know that `102 51 0 153` should become `170 85 0 153`

Comment: `buf[0] *= buf[3]; buf[1] *= buf[3]; buf[2] *= buf[3]` IIRC

Comment: I might be stupid here but 127x127 = 16129, not 255.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that it should be done with floats, i.e. `buf[0] = 0xff * ((buf[0] / 0xff) * (buf[3] / 0xff))` or just `buf[0] *= buf[3] / 0xff`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. However, take the green in `102 51 0 153`, thus `51×(153/255) = 30.6` and not 85. If I add the original 51, we are close at 81.6. That doesn't work for the red though, `102x(153/255)+102)=163.2` not 170

Comment: What you're asking is to convert colours from being premultiplied by alpha to original values. In that case you should **divide** by alpha: `buf[0] /= buf[3] / 0xff`

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko Your statement "it's your responsibility to return correct colour values from fragment shaders" is not quite correct. You can return non-premultiplied values from the shader even if the default framebuffer has pre-multiplied values. It is the _blending equation_ that must be correct.

Comment: @WestLangley that's why I've used generic word "correct":). If for example some tricky blending is done in a fragment shader, GL blending isn't used and `premultipliedAlpha` is set, the shader should output premultiplied colors itself.