# WebGL gl_FragColor alpha behave differently in Chrome with Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, graphics, webgl

Code below draws three triangles `alpha` value 0.5 with `{premultipliedAlpha: false}`.

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl', {premultipliedAlpha: false});

const canvasWidthHeight = 300;
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 0.4);
// gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const vertexShaderSource = `
  attribute vec2 position;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  // All shaders have a main function
  void main() {
    vec2 glSpacePosition = (position / resolution) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(glSpacePosition * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
  }
`;

const fragmentShaderSource = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
 
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
`;

function createShader(gl, type, shaderSource) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  const success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!success) {
    console.warn(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
  }

  return shader;
}

const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  const success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (!success) {
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
  }

  return program;
}

const program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

// We created a program on GPU, so the next step is supplying data.
const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
const resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'resolution');
const colorUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'color');

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, canvasWidthHeight, canvasWidthHeight);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

function drawRandomizedTriangles() {
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    0, canvasWidthHeight,
    canvasWidthHeight, 0
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, 0, 0, 1, 0.5);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0 + 50, 0,
    0 + 50, canvasWidthHeight,
    canvasWidthHeight + 50, 0
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, 1, 0, 0, 0.5);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0 + 100, 0,
    0 + 100, canvasWidthHeight,
    canvasWidthHeight + 100, 0
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, 1, 1, 1, 0.5);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

drawRandomizedTriangles();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Result in Chrome:
[image]

Result in Firefox:
[image]

The result in Firefox is what I expected.

I think it's not related to WebGL's blend since it's about blending `gl_FragColor` with drawing buffer instead of browser DOM, in this case, the green-background Canvas.
(This thought is based on my understanding of how WebGL works)

Also: In Chrome, if the `gl_FragColor.rgb` is `vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, no matter what the `gl_FragColor.a` is, as long as `a` is not `0`, the output color is pure white(when the `rgb` is other values, it will behave much differently).
[image]
Here is the [code pen](https://codepen.io/davidguan/pen/mqWbZX) for the image above(don't want to pollute this question with too much code).

Update 1: I believe this is not a blending issue, if we enable blend by:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The result will like this:[image]

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! I forgot `{premultipliedAlpha: false}` in the original post. My environment is FF56 Mac OS.

Comment: Hi, @Rabbid76 thanks! as the question description, I think this issue doesn't related to `blend`

Comment: Hi, @Rabbid76 I update the description again, can you have a look? Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome and is [fixed in version 64](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html).

Comment: @gman, thanks! I downloaded 64 with the link you sent, but find no difference with 62 when testing.

Comment: Strange. [Here is 62 (stable Chrome) for me](https://imgur.com/JPlict3) and [here is 64.0.3263.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)](https://imgur.com/8BUhn1N). Oh, heck. I see it's broken again in 64.0.3264.0 ☹️  Here's the [bug link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599285)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anser this question myself.

As @gman said in the comment area, this is a bug in chromium.
Here is the [bug link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599285)(thanks to @gman again).